# how to use $http.get to fetch php data from the same page

Tags: php, html, angularjs, controller

hope you fine and well ,

i want to ask if it possible to fetch data using $http.get from the same page , 
to go deep in details :

i have a php file called (MY_FILE.php) that contains : PHP,HTML and SCRIPT codes , 
in the PHP section i executed sql select statment, and im trying to fetch the selected data in the script to use it in the html part , is this possible ?!

php part :

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from table");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);

?>
```

script part :

```
fetch.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("MY_FILE.php")
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            })
            .error(function() {
                $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
            });
    }]);
```

when i use any of the selected data in the html section nothing appear and stay blank.

any idea ?!

Comment: declare $scope.data = {}; in controller before $http.get

Comment: thank you but nothing changed .

Comment: Can you log out the data you get back from the request to confirm that you actually get something back? Log out `$scope.data` after you've set it.

Comment: Use promises https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http . You need to use .then()  instead of .success()

Comment: Won't work if that file outputs anything other than the json for the `$http` request

Comment: How your `view` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The code is right, but the issue with using $http.get for the same page is when you use `print json_encode($data);` for returning response to the $http call, rather then returning call to $http, it prints the data on the page. So it returns nothng. So its better to use another page and using another page will be more user friendly as well because the page won't refresh for fetching the results. Secondly, because of the asynchronous nature of $http, the program will keep on executing and it won't be waiting for the php code to run and showing result. As soon as the php code is completely executed it will show the result.

And if you want everything to happen on same page you can simply use

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['varname']))
    {}
    ?> and
    <html>
    <form action="" method="POST" > 

    </form></html>
```